# NAT on outside interface alternatives

Tags: cisco, nat

I am struggling to configure some Cisco routers with NAT out of multiple outside interfaces.  The interfaces are considered as alternatives: use the first one that works.

**Question: what's the configuration for "NAT with the outside interface that you're routing out of" ?**

The equipment is a WAN of telemetry networks, each consisting of a Cisco 867VAE with a number of telemetry devices underneath.  These per-site routers are connected to the internet on a variety of ADSL, Fibre+ONT, ethernet methods.

I am configuring them for a "backup route" mechanisms, so that if the main link goes down, they can be connected temporarily to some network supporting DHCP.  Then they reconnect and central staff, not on site, can figure out what to do.  A critical part of the problem is that the site-visiting person doesn't know how (and isn't permitted) to change the Cisco config.

If it's plugged in and working, we want all traffic to go through isp1.  If for some reason that's down, and isp2 is working and up, then use that.  There is no load sharing, balancing or anything like that.

In the following image, any packet leaving dialer1 should have dialer1's PPP-assigned address; any packet leaving vlan1000 should have vlan1000's DHCP-assigned address.

```
      isp1       isp2
       |          |
  +----+----------+-----+
  | dialer1    vlan1000 |   outside
--|----------R8---------|--   NAT
  | vlan1               |   inside
  +---+-----------------+
      |
    telemetry units
```

A sample router is configured with

```
hostname R8

interface Dialer1
 description for adsl
 ip address negotiated
 ip nat outside
 encapsulation ppp
 dialer pool 1
 ppp chap hostname ...

interface FastEthernet3
 switchport access vlan 1000
 no ip address

interface Vlan1
 description main local address on default vlan
 ip address 192.168.8.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside

interface Vlan1000
 description auto uplink
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer1
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 dhcp 10
```

All that works fine as described: we use dialer1 if it works, else vlan1000 if that works.  The vlan1000 / fe3 config is just because the 867VAE doesn't have L3 ethernet ports.

The question is about NAT:

```
ip nat inside source list NATLIST interface Vlan1000 overload
ip access-list standard NATLIST
 permit 192.168.8.0 0.0.0.255
```

What I'm imagining is

```
ip nat inside source list NATLIST interface dialer1 overload
ip nat inside source list NATLIST interface Vlan1000 overload
ip access-list standard NATLIST
 permit 192.168.8.0 0.0.0.255
```

But of course you can't have multiple `ip nat inside source NATLIST`

EDIT: When the second one is added, it replaces the first.  Am I missing something?

(Example here using two VLAN interfaces and list 10 per Ron's answer)

```
gwhqtun1#show run | include nat
 ip nat outside
 ip nat outside
ip nat inside source list 10 interface Vlan1000 overload
gwhqtun1#conf term
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
gwhqtun1(config)#ip nat inside source list 10 interface Vlan2000 overload
gwhqtun1(config)#exit
gwhqtun1#show run | include nat
 ip nat outside
 ip nat outside
ip nat inside source list 10 interface Vlan2000 overload
```

Cisco IOS Software, C860 Software (C860VAE-ADVSECURITYK9-M), Version 15.2(4)M3, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)

Grateful for any suggestions, most especially if I've done something wrong or silly.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Please let me know if you were able to sort this out with my answer below.

Comment: Did any answer help you?

Answer (score 2):

In this kind of setup, I always prefer route-map to access-list.

To my best knowledge, you are right that you cannot have multiple following lines. The last line (and only one) you apply will stay:

```
ip nat inside source list NATLIST interface Interface_#1 overload
ip nat inside source list NATLIST interface Interface_#2 overload

or

ip nat inside source route-map routemap_name interface Interface_#1 overload
ip nat inside source route-map routemap_name interface Interface_#2 overload
```

So the trick is to use different route_map (or access-list) names for differnet nat statements. Here are examples:

```
!
route-map ISP1 permit 10
 match ip address NATLIST
 match interface dialer1
!
route-map ISP2 permit 10
 match ip address NATLIST
 match interface vlan1000
!
ip nat inside source route-map ISP1 interface dialer1 overload
ip nat inside source route-map ISP2 interface vlan1000 overload
!
```

I hope it is helpful and you can make it work!

Answer (score 1):

```
ip nat inside source route-map isp1 interface dialer1 overload
ip nat inside source route-map isp2 interface vlan1000 overload
!
route-map isp1 permit 10
  match interface dialer1
!
route-map isp2 permit 10
  match interface vlan1000
```

That should get you the per-interface NAT you're looking for.

Keep in mind, when your default route swings from interface to interface, all connections will break. For example, if dialer1 fails, traffic will shift to ISP2 (dhcp, metric 10); when dialer1 comes back up, it will be the default route and no traffic will flow towards ISP2, even though it's still functional.

Comment: Your route_map would not work because it does not match ACL for source LAN/inside network.

Comment: It doesn't have to. This will NAT anything leaving either interface. An ACL only exists because that command syntax requires one. (it be an "any any" ACL and do just the same.) For the record, my route-maps have deny acls to create "nat0" rules -- stuff NOT to NAT.